# How can I call a RESTful .Net WCF Service from cURL?

Tags: terminal, windows, curl, .net

I created a WCF service, which I am hosting on a server. I can successfully call the service from a desktop application successfully, but I have trouble calling the service from `curl` at a terminal prompt.

Here is the server call:

> http://192.168.1.80:9000/WcfServiceLibrary1.CRUDContact

If I wanted to call a method, say, GetVersionInfo, I would do:

> http://192.168.1.80:9000/WcfServiceLibrary1.CRUDContact/GetVersionInfo

In a .Net application, I would append `/mex/` before the method call, but that is neither here nor there.

cURL communicates with the server to a level, because if I specify any other URI than the first, I get a 404 error, as expected.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Not Found</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Not Found</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

If I call just the base without any method, I get what I would see inside a browser, namely a screen showing how to call the service from C# or VB. If I call using any method, even a made up one, I get nothing, literally, just a blank line. I even captured the output to a file and nothing.

cURL lines that I tried:

```
 $ curl http://192.168.1.80:9000/WcfServiceLibrary1.CRUDContact/mex/GetVersionInfo
 $ curl http://192.168.1.80:9000/WcfServiceLibrary1.CRUDContact/GetVersionInfo
 $ curl -H "Accept: application/xml" http://192.168.1.80:9000/WcfServiceLibrary1.CRUDContact/GetVersionInfo http://192.168.1.80:9000/WcfServiceLibrary1.CRUDContact/mex/GetVersionInfo
```

I tried several other variants, but always empty.

How do I get XML back from a RESTful WCF service?

Comment: Might be helpful - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/20f0e900-0909-45a1-ae4d-92e52f38d513/how-can-i-make-curl-representation-of-my-wcf-service?forum=wcf.

Comment: Even though you're asking a Q about `curl` that is on topic on this site, I feel your Q would probably be better served on SO, so I'm going to migrate it.